# What causes a repartitioning to occur when turning an RDD into a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use `Window.sum` function to get the sum of a value in an RDD, but when I convert the DataFrame to an RDD, I found that the result's has only one partition. When does the repartitioning occur?

```
 val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8), 4)
    val df = rdd.toDF("values").
        withColumn("csum", sum(col("values")).over(Window.orderBy("values")))
    df.show()
    println(s"numPartitions ${df.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
    // 1
    //df is:
//    +------+----+
//    |values|csum|
//    +------+----+
//    |     1|   1|
//    |     2|   3|
//    |     3|   6|
//    |     4|  10|
//    |     5|  15|
//    |     6|  21|
//    |     7|  28|
//    |     8|  36|
//    +------+----+
```

I add partitionBy in Window ,but the result is error,what should i do?this is my change code:

```
     val rdd=sc.parallelize(List(1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8),4)
        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(m_sparkCtx)
        import sqlContext.implicits._
        val df = rdd.toDF("values").withColumn("csum", sum(col("values")).over(Window.partitionBy("values").orderBy("values")))
        df.show()
        println(s"numPartitions ${df.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
       //1
//df is:
//    +------+----+
//    |values|csum|
//    +------+----+
//    |     1|   1|
//    |     6|   6|
//    |     3|   3|
//    |     5|   5|
//    |     4|   4|
//    |     8|   8|
//    |     7|   7|
//    |     2|   2|
//    +------+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window` function has `partitionBy` api for grouping the `dataframe` and `orderBy` to order the grouped `rows` in ascending or descending order.

In your first case you hadn't defined `partitionBy`, thus all the values were grouped in one `dataframe` for ordering purpose and thus shuffling the data into one partition.

But in your second case you had `partitionBy` defined on `values` itself. So since each value are distinct, each `row` is grouped into individual groups.

The `partition` in second case is 200 as that is the default partitioning defined in `spark` when you haven't defined partitions and shuffle occurs

To get the same result with your first case, you need to add another `column` with grouping value so that you can group them as in your first case i.e. into one group .

```
val rdd=sc.parallelize(List(1,3,2,4,5,6,7,8),4)
val df = rdd.toDF("values").withColumn("grouping", lit("group"))
  df.withColumn("csum", sum(col("values")).over(Window.partitionBy("grouping").orderBy("values"))).drop("grouping").show(false)
```

By doing this I see that your original partitioning is preserved.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: what do you mean by `what should I do?`?

Comment: what should i do to get the same result with partitionBy

Comment: I will answer in your other question . if its fine with you please update the other question with this comment's question as well.